# Loop through input

Tags: python, loops, data-structures

I have created a morse code, I want to loop input question until the user press on 'Stop'
and maybe create an input question asking the user to continue or stop the loop.

```py
def to_morse_code(text):
    code = {'A':'.-','B':'-...','C':'-.-.','D':'-..','E':'.',
         'F':'..-.','G':'--.','H':'....','I':'..','J':'.---',
         'K':'-.-','L':'.-..','M':'--','N':'-.','O':'---',
         'P':'.--.','Q':'--.-','R':'.-.','S':'...','T':'-',
         'U':'..-','V':'...-','W':'.--','X':'-..-','Y':'-.--',
         'Z':'--..', ' ':'.....'}

    morse_code = ""
    for x in text:
        morse_code += code[x.upper()]
    return morse_code
 
text = input("Enter text to conver to Mose Code: ")
print(to_morse_code(text))
```

I have tried While loop with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
while True:
    text = input("Enter text to convert to Morse Code (or ctrl+c to quit): ")
    print(to_morse_code(text))
```

Comment: It's not working, The question "Enter text to convert....." asked only once, maybe i wasn't clear, i want  it to ask once than i type something than i want it to ask again and again until i press on 'stop'.

Comment: @TamirRozenfeld The correct thing happens when I  run this on my PC, there must be something else wrong.